jQuery $('CLASS').on('click tap touchstart', function(event) not working on mobile
EDITED AND REPOSTED
as the title says, the function is working properly on desktop, but not on mobile. The code is below, but I've removed most of it because it's quite repetitive and long, but if you need the entire script I'm happy to provide it.
Thanks!
HTML
<span id="brxe-wlyncw" class="brxe-button main-cta-button pricing-btn faq-btn bricks-button bricks-background-primary">Pricing</span>

<div id="brxe-bilrmd" class="brxe-container pricing-faq"></div>
<div id="brxe-bilrmd" class="brxe-container plans-faq"></div>
<div id="brxe-bilrmd" class="brxe-container seo-faq"></div>
<div id="brxe-bilrmd" class="brxe-container websites-faq"></div>

jQuery
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('.faq-btn').on('click tap touchstart', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if($(this).hasClass('pricing-btn')){

    $('.pricing-faq').show();
    $('.plans-faq').hide();
    $('.seo-faq').hide();
    $('.websites-faq').hide();

} else if ($(this).hasClass('plans-btn')){

    $('.pricing-faq').hide();
    $('.plans-faq').show();
    $('.seo-faq').hide();
    $('.websites-faq').hide();

} else if ($(this).hasClass('seo-btn')){

    $('.pricing-faq').hide();
    $('.plans-faq').hide();
    $('.seo-faq').show();
    $('.websites-faq').hide();

} else if ($(this).hasClass('websites-btn')){

    $('.pricing-faq').hide();
    $('.plans-faq').hide();
    $('.seo-faq').hide();
    $('.websites-faq').show();
}
});

});


Please add the relevant HTML to create an actual [mre]

"Quite repetitive" means you can make it DRY: $('.pricing-faq').toggle($(this).is('.pricing-btn')); $('.plans-faq').toggle($(this).is('.plans-btn')); $('.seo-faq').toggle($(this).is('.seo-btn')); $('.websites-faq').toggle($(this).is('.websites-btn'));

We added event.preventDefault() so that button clicks work properly especially on mobile devices
We have added CSS to style the buttons and the FAQ sections as per your design requirements.
CSS Code here:
.faq-section {
  display: none;
}

jQuery code here:
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.faq-btn').on('click touchstart', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  // event prevent Default behaviors on touch modify
        
// Same code use here
        if ($(this).hasClass('pricing-btn')){
          $('.pricing-faq').show();
          $('.plans-faq').hide();
          $('.seo-faq').hide();
          $('.websites-faq').hide();
        }else if ($(this).hasClass('plans-btn')) {
            $('.pricing-faq').hide();
            $('.plans-faq').show();
            $('.seo-faq').hide();
            $('.websites-faq').hide();
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('seo-btn')){
            $('.pricing-faq').hide();
            $('.plans-faq').hide();
            $('.seo-faq').show();
            $('.websites-faq').hide();
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('websites-btn')){
            $('.pricing-faq').hide();
            $('.plans-faq').hide();
            $('.seo-faq').hide();
            $('.websites-faq').show();
        }
    });
});

Please try this code works well on both desktop and mobile devices.
